# Error during product fetching by subsubcategory: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: mysql, node.js, flutter, dart

Model

[image]

controller

[image]

The Flutter application allows users to select an image either from the gallery or by capturing a photo using the device's camera.
Upon selection, the image file is retrieved by the Flutter application.
File Handling in Flutter:

In the Flutter application, the selected image is represented as a File object, which encapsulates the image data.
Conversion to Bytes:

Before sending the image data to the server, it needs to be converted into bytes. This conversion is performed using the readAsBytes() method on the File object in Flutter. This method reads the contents of the file and returns them as a list of bytes (List).
Sending Image Data to the Server:

The Flutter application sends the image data along with other product details to the server using an HTTP POST request.
The image data, now represented as a list of bytes, is included in the request body.
Server-side Handling:

The server, implemented using Node.js and Express, receives the HTTP POST request containing the product details and the image data.
Multer, a middleware for handling multipart/form-data, is used for processing file uploads in Node.js.
Multer middleware is configured to store uploaded files in memory (memoryStorage()), and the configured storage is used by the upload.single('image') middleware to handle the image upload.
Image Storage in MySQL Database:

Upon receiving the image data, the server prepares an SQL INSERT query to insert the product details, including the image data, into the MySQL database.
The image data, represented as a list of bytes (List), is directly inserted into the Image column of the product table.
In the product table schema, the Image column is likely defined with a data type suitable for storing binary data, such as BLOB (Binary Large Object).
Binary Representation:

In the MySQL database, the image data is stored as a binary large object (BLOB), which preserves the binary representation of the image.
The binary data of the image is stored directly in the Image column of the product table.}

I tried to display product: name, price, image, description.
But, only products with no images are displaying but not products with images.

Comment: Please read [mre] and [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)